# How to replace http links to https in whole page using Greasemonkey?

Tags: http, https, replace, greasemonkey

Is there anyway to replace any http link to https in whole page ?
there are some scripts in userscripts.org but they only redirect the url and they don't change html content ..

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish.  You want to just change the links, that is: `<a>` tags? ... If only that, why?  If privacy/security is your concern, a Greasemonkey script is not the best tool for that job.

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned about security and privacy, you are much **better off installing and using an extension like [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere).**

An extension has more power to enforce SSL on: links, images, video and sound files, CSS and javascript files, flash objects, AJAX calls, etc.  Whereas a Greasemonkey script, or userscript, can have a devil of a time doing just part of that.

But, if you really just want to change just the links (`<a>` nodes) in a page, that is not too hard to do.  The biggest thing to account for is sites that add links via AJAX.  For that reason, use jQuery and `waitForKeyElements()` to handle all the links.

Here's **a complete script** to get you started:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Remap links to https
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
waitForKeyElements ("a", remapToSSL);

function remapToSSL (jNode) {
    var node    = jNode.get (0);

    if (node.protocol === "http:") {
        node.protocol = "https:";
    }
}
```

Comment: HTTPS Everywhere Sucks. It uses a predefined list of sites for which it works, and there is no easy way to extend that list. Most of the time it just won't work with the site you want to use it with.